# error while converting text to image using php

Tags: php

// Create the image
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 30);

// Create some colors
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);

// The text to draw
$text = 'अन्ग्रेज़ी से हिन्दी';
// Replace path by your own font path
$font = 'mangal.ttf';

// Add some shadow to the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 11, 21, $grey, $font, $text);

// Add the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);

// Using imagepng() results in clearer text compared with imagejpeg()
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>

The output text is not same as the input text

Comment: I assume you mean you want to render the text as a graphic?

Comment: Yes, is it possible using javascript

Comment: I'm sure it's possible. Javascript is turing complete, so you can do anything. Now whether it's easy or efficient... and whether there are libraries available to do it... those are entirely different questions.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? You could do this pretty trivially using the canvas element.

Comment: i have edited my question, just take a look at it

Comment: That is cool. Originally the question was "Is it possible to convert text to image using javascript?" And now you've changed it to completely different one. Why not to create new question? That will be at least honest.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `<canvas>` for that, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Drawing_text_using_a_canvas

Answer (score 0):

Not directly; javascript isn't supposed to be allowed to poke around in the guts of binary elements like images.  You could render the text using a canvas element, or alternatively apply WebGL, but this is probably not what you want.  If it absolutely has to be an image, the most portable way to do that is to make a web app that renders the text to an image and echos it back to a client.  Using this, you can easily take a blob of text, create an image element that pulls the object back and then display that in the browser.

Comment: i tried using imagettftext in php, it works fine for english language but not for indian languages such as Hindi.

Comment: Ah, then you may be out of luck with using that method (through PHP anyway).  I found the following question on localization and imagegettftext : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666105/missing-chars-in-jpgraph